# How to see that this set is countable?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, elementary-set-theory

Let $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a monotone function and consider the set $S$ of all points $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)\neq \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x).$$

I want to show that this set is countable, but I'm not finding any way to do it. I thought one way would be to show that this set is discrete, so that it is countable. For that to happen, I would need to show that there is no convergent sequence $(x_n)$ of points of $S$ all different than $a$ whose limit is $a$.

My idea then is to suppose there is such a sequence $(x_n)$. Then $x_n\in S$ and $\lim x_n = a$ with $x_n\neq a$. In that case we have $\lim_{x\to x_n^-}f(x)\neq \lim_{x\to x_n^+}f(x)$.

Intuition says this should contradict $f$ being monotone, but I'm not finding a way to prove it.

So how can I finish this proof? Is my strategy correct? If so how do I finish it? If not, how should I prove this result?

Comment: This question looks relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84870/

Comment: The set of discontinuities need not be discrete.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $X=\{a: \lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f(x)\not=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x)\}$, and assume $f$ is nondecreasing.

For $a\in X$, let $I_a=(\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f(x), \lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x))$ be the "gap" between the left and right limits.

What can you say about $I_a$ and $I_b$ for $a, b$ distinct elements of $X$?

Comment: The idea is that $\forall x \in R ,   \forall n\in Z^+ [\infty>f(x)-f(x-n)\geq \sum_{a\in X\cap [x-n,x]} I_a \geq 0] $ and that $I_a>0$ for any $a\in X$.

Comment: @user254665 Bwah? I can't figure out what that means. Also, $I_a$ is an *interval*, not a number, so I'm not sure what "$I_a>0$" means. Regardless, it's needlessly complicated - there's a much simpler approach . . .

Comment: Sorry.I should have written $|I_a|$ and also $x\in Z$ and fixed $n=1$.  If $X $  is uncountable then $X\cap[x-1,x] $ls uncountable for some $x\in Z$. But then ,for some $q\in Q^+$ we have $\{a\in X\cap [x-1,x] : |I_a|>q\}$  uncountable.

Comment: @user254665 I see. This is still needlessly complicated - since $I_a$ is a nonempty interval for $a\in X$, $I_a$ contains a rational $q_a$. Distinct $I_a$s are disjoint. So there's an injection from $X$ into $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: works anyway. i always find a more complicated proof.