# Why can we 'choose' continuity points?

Tags: probability-distributions, continuity

Let $F$ and $F_n$ be  distribution functions with $\lim_n F_n(x)=F(x)$ for all continuity points $x$ of $F$. In a proof there is the following part:

> Block quote [...] choose the finite points $a=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_r=b$ as continuity points of $F(x)$ and such that $F(a)\leq \varepsilon, 1-F(b)\leq\varepsilon$, and $\lvert x_{j+1}-x_{j}\rvert\leq\varepsilon$ and, for $n\geq N$, $\lvert F(x_j)-F_n(x_j)\rvert\leq\varepsilon$ for all $j$.

My question: Why can we simply choose such finite many continuity points?? For me this falls from sky without any reason.

Comment: I suspect you want $F$ and $F_n$ to be related *cumulative* distribution functions.  If not, this is false.  This also depends on how $F$ and $F_n$ are related.

Comment: Probably $F_n\to F$ pointwise

Comment: $F_n$ to F pointwise for all continuity points of F.

Comment: Can U update the question to include this info? (Otherwise, it's not clear)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set of continuity points of $F$ ($C_F$) is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (as the complement of at most countable set of jumps of $F$). Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and consider points $a,b\in C_F$ s.t. $F(a)\le \varepsilon$ and $1-F(b)\le \varepsilon$. Then split $[a,b]$ into $r_{\varepsilon}=2(a-b)/\varepsilon$ intervals of length $\varepsilon/2$. We get $r_{\varepsilon}+1$ equally spaced points $\{x_i\}$. If $x_i\in \mathbb{R}\setminus C_F$ for some $0\le i\le r_{\varepsilon}$, then the denseness of $C_F$ ensures that we can peak a point $x_i'\in B(x_i,\varepsilon/4)\cap C_F$. After handling all such collisions, the resulting set of points satisfies the required condition.

Finally, points $a$ and $b$ exist by the properties of the CDF and the denseness of $C_F$ (similarly).

Comment: Thanks! By the way: Can we say something about how many continuity points exist? We know that at most countably many  discontinuity points exist but is there a smilar result for continuity points?

Comment: @H.Hawks $C_F=\mathbb{R}\setminus J_F$, where $J_F$ (a set of discontinuity points) is at most countable

Comment: Hence we have uncountably many continuity points, don't we?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "distribution function" you mean a [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF), and not a [generalized function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

In that case, we note that any CDF is [nondecreasing so that it admits only simple discontinuities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84870/how-to-show-that-a-set-of-discontinuous-points-of-an-increasing-function-is-at-m). <s>Can you figure out the rest?</s> Actually, reading your question more carefully, the result does not seem obvious to me. But this is probably the right path to go down.

Comment: At most countably many discontinuity points means that we have uncountably many continuity poimts, so in particular we can choose finite many? - If yes: Why with these desired properties?