# A possible fault of the proof of that discontinuous points of monotone function is at most countable

Tags: real-analysis

Here's proof of Royden's real analysis: 
[image]

My question is do we real have **bounded interval $[f(a),f(b)]$**. Because if we let $f(a)=-\infty$ and $f(b)=\infty$, so is this proof wrong?

By the way, I prefer to prove this in this way:[How to show that a set of discontinuous points of an increasing function is at most countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84870/how-to-show-that-a-set-of-discontinuous-points-of-an-increasing-function-is-at-m) .

Comment: Royden assumes that $f$ is increasing on the closed interval $[a,b]$ in the second sentence of the proof.

Comment: @DanielFischer But it still cannot imply interval $[f(a),f(b)]$ bounded, right?

Comment: If $f$ is assumed real-valued rather than extended-real-valued, then $\{f(a), f(b)\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, so the interval is bounded.

Comment: You are right. Then how about the extended-real-valued case?

Comment: Slight modification. Assuming that $f$ attains both infinities, let $\alpha = \sup \{ x : f(x) = -\infty\}$ and $\beta = \inf \{ x : f(x) = +\infty\}$. Apply the given proof to $f\lvert_{(\alpha,\beta)}$, and note that all discontinuities of $f$ lie in $[\alpha,\beta]$.