# if $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing, show that $f$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions over $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

if $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing, show that $f$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous  functions over $[0,1]$

Intuitively this makes sense but I am having trouble with showing why there would be a sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to $f$.

Clearly there is a sequence converging pointwise to $f$, I can set:
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f_n = f$.

How to prove there is at least one which is made up of continuous functions $f_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ over $[0,1]$ I can't quite figure out the argument.

Comment: How about $f_n:= f-1/2^n$? We know $f$ is a.e. continuous, since it is monotone. We define it as above wherever $f$ is continuous and then extend on the countably-many points where it is not? Isn't the set of points of continuity dense in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @gary Increasing doesn't imply continuous, hence $f - \frac{1}{2^n}$ isn't necessarily continuous.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: It (meaning monotonous)  implies a.e continuous, though, and I am defining it as $f-1/2^n$ at the points where it is continuous, which I believe is dense in $[0,1]$ and then extending from a dense subset into $[0,1]$.

Comment: @gary Suppose $f(x)=x+H(x-0.5)$. This is continuous on $[0,0.5)\cup(0.5,1]$, so $f_1(x)=f(x)-1$ on $[0,0.5)\cup(0.5,1]$. How do you propose to define $f_1(0.5)$ to make $f_1$ continuous?

Comment: @gary at any discontinuities of $f$ wouldn't $f - \frac{1}{2^n}$ have a discontinuity at the point as well?

Comment: @stewbasic: What is $H$? And wouldn't $f(0.5)=0.5$ make $f$ continuous?

Comment: It's a collary of Lusin's theorem.

Comment: @oliverjones: $f$ is defined that way at points of continuity. And if $f$ is not continuous , unless I am missing something, it can be extended.

Comment: @gary $H$ is the Heaviside function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

Comment: @gary you are missing something. Being continuous a.e.  doesn't mean it can be extended to a continuous function. A function with a single jump discontinuity is a counterexample.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: But this seems to contradict the result that every unifomly continuous function defined on a dense subset can be extended continuously. $f$ is a.e. continuous on a compact subset, therefore it is a.e. uniformly continuous by compactness.What am I missing?

Comment: @gary I think the gap in your argument is that although continuity on a compact set implies uniform continuity, the same isn't true for a.e. continuity. In any case your conclusion is clearly false for a function with a step discontinuity (eg see my link).

Comment: @stewbasic: D'oh myself: the set of points where f is continuous is not necessarily compact.

Comment: @stewbasic I was given the hint: prove for any interval of $[0,1]$ that the characteristic function is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions. Which I believe I can then define $f_n(x) = \max(0, 1 - n\chi_I)$ where $I \subseteq [0,1]$. But I don't see how this helps.

Comment: Why do you consider the pointwise limit?

Comment: @C.Ding I don't understand your question.

Comment: Why do you need the pointwise-limit other than a.e.-limit?

Comment: @C.Ding because that is the question I was asked.  a.e.-limit is not what was asked for so I can't just use that.

Comment: "A function whose continuity points are everywhere dense in every nonempty perfect set can be represented as a limit of continuous functions." This statement is taken from Boas, *A primer of real functions*, page 125. I suspect that this could be useful, since a monotone function is continuous axcept at countably many points where one-sided limits exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the set of discontinuities of $f$. We know that $\mathcal{D}$ is at most countable, so we enumerate this set by $\mathcal{D} = \{ x_0, x_1, \cdots \}$. Now for each $n \geq 0$, let

$$ \Pi_n = \{ \tfrac{k}{2^n} : 0 \leq k \leq 2^n \} \cup \{ x_0, \cdots, x_n \} $$

and define $f_n : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ as the linear interpolation of the points $\{ (x, f(x)) : x \in \Pi_n\}$ ordered from left to right. Then

- It is clear that $f_n$ is continuous and increasing for each $n\geq 0$.
- If $x \in \cup_{n\geq 0} \Pi_n$, then $x \in \Pi_N$ for some $N$ and hence by construction, $f_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $n \geq N$. So we have $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$.
- If $x \in [0, 1] \setminus \mathcal{D}$, then for each fixed $m$ there is $a_m, b_m \in \Pi_m$ such that $a_m \leq x \leq b_m$ and $|b_m - a_m| \leq 2^{-m}$. Taking limit as $n\to\infty$ to the inequality $f_n(a_m) \leq f_n(x) \leq f_n(b_m)$, we obtain

  \begin{align*}
  f(a_m)
  = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n (a_m)
  &\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} f_n (x) \\
  &\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n (x)
   \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n (b_m)
   = f(b_m).
  \end{align*}

  Taking $m \to \infty$, both $(a_m)$ and $(b_m)$ converge to $x$. Since $x$ is a continuity point of $f$, we have

  $$ f(x) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} f_n (x) \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n (x) \leq f(x) $$

  and hence $f_n(x) \to f(x)$.

Combining altogether, it follows that $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $[0, 1]$ as expected.

Comment: Doesn't a sequence of continuous function on a compact set converge uniformly so that the limit function is continuous?

Comment: @gary, Continuity is not guaranteed if you take pointwise limit. Recall the archetypal example: $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0, 1]$. I suspect that you are confusing this with the statement that a continuous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous (or with its obvious generalizations).

Comment: No, I just thought sequences that were defined on a compact space converged uniformly to a continuous function, but you reminded me of that counterexample.

Comment: @SangchulLee when you say linear interpolation you mean something like the Lagrange polynomial?

Comment: @oliverjones, It is rather a very straightforward one, joining successive data points by line segments. Check [*this page*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Interpolation_of_a_data_set) to see a picture!

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: This answer dose not answer the OP's question. Just see it as a reference.

Since $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing, it is a bounded Borel measurable function. By Lusin's theorem, there is a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of continuous functions such that
$f_n=f$ on a Borel set $E_n$ which satisfies $m\{[0,1]\backslash E_n\}<\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m\{[0,1]\backslash E_n\}<\infty$, for almost every point in $[0,1]$, it is contained in finte sets of $\{[0,1]\backslash E_n\}$ and therefore $f_n$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: If $E_n=[0,1]\setminus\{0.5\}$ then $m([0,1]\setminus E_n)=m(\{0.5\})=0$ but $0.5$ is in infinitely many $[0,1]\setminus E_n$? I think it's not enough to know that $f_n$ approximates $f$ well almost everywhere, because you need different sequences depending on whether $f$ is left or right continuous at a jump discontinuity.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed "almost" in your last sentence. The question asks for $f_n$ to converge to $f$ at every point, not just almost every point.

Comment: I need the sequence of functions to converge at every point (pointwise) and I don't currently have that theorem at my disposal.

Comment: By the same token I can use my argument, since a Real-valued function can only have countably-many jumps.

Comment: @stewbasic If every incresing function is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions, then so is every bounded variation function. Is this true?

Comment: @C.Ding I'm not sure, but I'd be interested in seeing how that follows; would you mind giving more detail?

Comment: @stewbasic I'm also not sure , and we may consider a sigular function here: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cantor_ternary_function

Answer (score 2):

Here is another answer, which main idea is : if $f$ is right or left continuous, there is an "explicit" solution (see the integrals below).

> **Claim :** Every increasing function $f$ can be written as a sum of an increasing right-continuous function and a left-continuous function.

*Proof :* the set of points at which $f$ is discontinuous is [at most countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84870/how-to-show-that-a-set-of-discontinuous-points-of-an-increasing-function-is-at-m) : it will be denoted $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Now we take $g : x \mapsto \sum \limits_{\substack{n \in \mathbb{N}\\ a_n \le x}} f(a_n)-f(a_n^-)$ and $h = f-g$. It is easy to show that $g$ is right-continuous. If $x \notin \{a_n\}$, $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x$, so $h$ is continuous at $x$. If $x=a_n$, $g(t) \underset{t \to x^-}{\longrightarrow} g(x)-\big( f(a_n)-f(a_n^-) \big)$, so $h(t) \underset{t \to x^-}{\longrightarrow} f(a_n^-)-g(x)+\big( f(a_n)-f(a_n^-) \big)=h(x)$. Hence $f=g+h$ with $f$ increasing and right-continuous, and $h$ left-continuous.

$ $

If we write $f=g+h$ with $g$, $h$ as in the claim, both $f$ and $g$ are increasing, thus locally bounded and with at most countably many discontinuity points. Hence $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable, and so is $h$. For $n \ge 1$, we can thus consider : $$
g_n : x \mapsto n \displaystyle{\int_x^{x+\frac{1}{n}}} g(t)dt,\quad \
h_n : x \mapsto n \displaystyle{\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^x} h(t)dt, \quad \ 
f_n : x \mapsto g_n(x)+h_n(x).$$

As $g$ (*resp.* $h$) is right (*resp.* left)-continuous, it is easy to prove that for all $x$, $g_n(x) \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} g(x)$ and $h_n(x) \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} h(x)$, so $\big(f_n\big)_{n \ge 1}$ converges pointwise to $f$. As $g$ and $h$ are locally bounded, $g_n$ and $h_n$ are continuous for all $n$, and thus $\big( f_n \big)_{n \ge 1}$ is a sequence of continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

So: monotone functions are Baire-one functions, as you can see [here](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/414514-homework-2-monotone-and-baire-one-functions/) and [here](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2014/10/06/414514-simple-examples-of-baire-class-one-functions/). This means, by definition, that elements of this class are pointwise limits of continuous functions, see [here](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/huh.pdf). Hence the statement is proved.