# Two monotone functions which equal on rational numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $f,g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be increasing and $f(r)=g(r)$ for every $r\in\mathbb Q$. Must we have $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A potentially-more-interesting variant: are the functions equal *a.e.*?

Comment: @R. What does `a.e.` mean?

Comment: @R.. That would make a nice follow-up question. I think such functions will be equal in a cocountable set (and thus almost everywhere ("a.e.")), but I don't know if every cocountable set can be realized this way.

Comment: @R.. Wikipedia [monotonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) says an increasing function defined on an interval is differentiable almost everywhere. In particular continuous almost everywhere. So for almost any $x$, both $f$ and $g$ are continuous in that $x$, and so it is clear that they agree there. So if we accept Wikipedia's statement, your answer is yes.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen. A monotonic real function has only countably many discontinuities. In order for $f(x)\ne g(x)$ it is necessary that at least one of $f,g $ is discontinuous at $x.$

Comment: @EricDuminil. ... "a.e". means "almost everwhere" which means "except on a set of Lebesgue-measure $0.$" See my previous comment:  $f$ and $g$ agree except on a countable set, and countable sets are among the  measure-$0$ sets.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta.  See my comment above directed to JeppeStigNielsen.

Comment: They would be equal a.e. if they were continuous but there is a sudden fad to working with discontinuous functions and their alleged marvel structure no one can give support for.

Comment: @gary They would be equal **everywhere** if they were continuous, but that is not a hypothesis. They are monotone by hypothesis, but as the accepted answer shows, that's not enough for equality everywhere. But it **is** enough for equality **almost everywhere** since monotonicity implies continuity almost everywhere (even stronger: continuity everywhere except on a countable set).

Comment: @Bungo: I am aware that monotone functions between the Reals  are not just a.e. continuous  but a.e. differentiable. A question I find interesting is whether they are necessarily differentiable at the same points.

Comment: And moreover, the set of discontinuities is an $F_{\sigma}$ set.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. Take $$f(x)=x+\chi_{(\pi,+\infty)}(x)\,,\ \ \ g(x)=x+\chi_{[\pi,+\infty)}(x).$$
Here $\chi_A$ stands for the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $A$; i.e. $\chi_A$ is the function whose value at $x$ is $1$ if $x\in A$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I don't immediately see how these functions are increasing - perhaps you could explain?

Comment: Well x and chi are monotonously increasing, so their sum is too.

Comment: @user3490 Maybe it is easier to define $f$ as $f(x)=x$ for $x\le\pi$ and $f(x)=x+1$ for $x>\pi$. And define $g$ by $g(x)=x$ for $x<\pi$ and $g(x)=x+1$ for $x\ge\pi$. Can you imagine their graphs?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen. I was going to say that.

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer shows, it's not necessarily true that the functions are equal everywhere. However, we can show that the set of points where they are **not** equal is countable. (This implies, and in fact is stronger than, the statement that $f$ and $g$ are equal almost everywhere.)

First, note that if $x \in \mathbb R$ and both $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x$, then we can take any sequence $\{r_n\}$ of rationals converging to $x$, and we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(r_n) = f\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}r_n\right) = f(x)$$
where the first equality holds because $r_n \to x$ and $f$ is continuous at $x$. Similarly,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}g(r_n) = g(x)$$
Since $f(r_n) = g(r_n)$ for every $n$, this means that $f(x) = g(x)$. So, the functions are equal at any point where they are both continuous.

Furthermore, we know that $f$ and $g$ are monotone functions. This means that each function must be continuous everywhere except possibly on a countable set. For a proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84870/how-to-show-that-a-set-of-discontinuous-points-of-an-increasing-function-is-at-m), for example. Let $D_f$ and $D_g$ respectively denote the sets where $f$ and $g$ are discontinuous. These sets are countable. Note that $D_f \cup D_g$ is still countable (the union of two countable sets is countable), and $f$ and $g$ are both continuous (hence equal) everywhere in the complement of $D_f \cup D_g$.